# Why is this a duplicate?

Tags: support, closing

Why is [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/44217/is-your-left-hand-slower-than-your-right) a dupliate of [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35274/do-weapons-and-spells-in-the-off-hand-suffer-from-reduced-effectiveness)? I'm not asking if the attack is weaker, but if the animation is slower. Seems different to me.

Comment: There might be some overlap here, but I don't think an answer to the open question would necessarily answer yours (and the current answer doesn't as far as I can tell).  I think these are both good candidates to remain open; a little duplication isn't bad.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a subset of what is covered in the other question. The other question asks about anything that would reduce effectiveness, and having a slower attack rate would be one of those things.

Comment: `When dual wielding, is there a damage penalty to the offhand weapon`  He seems to be asking specifically about damage

Comment: @Joe "Do weapons and spells in the off-hand suffer from reduced effectiveness?"

Comment: A loss of attack speed *is* a loss of damage. The fact that it comes in the form of fewer attacks, rather than less damage *per attack* is, at the end of the day, purely semantic. I apologize if my question was unclear in that respect when I asked it. Regardless, the answer remains the same. (Actually, there is a *slight* benefit to the attack speed of the dual-strike attack if you are dual wielding with a dagger in the offhand and a slow weapon like a mace in the mainhand, but that's another story.)